# Não consigo compreender como o if que verifica se o objeto já existe na lista está funcionando. Alguem pode ME EXPLICAR, como está funcionando pfvr

Tags: javascript

```
var objetos = ['cadeira', 'impressora', 'garfo']
    console.log(objetos)

    function adicionar(){
        var objeto = document.getElementById('campo').value
        
       if(objeto === '' ){        
            alert('adicione um valor valido')
        }
        else if(objeto !== '' ){  
//EXATAMENTE ESSA PARTE DO CODIGO AQUI NN CONSIGO COMPREENDER//      
            if(objetos.indexOf(objeto)!== -1){
//EXATAMENTE ESSA PARTE DO CODIGO AQUI NN CONSIGO COMPREENDER//   
                alert('objeto já foi')
            }
            
        }    

       
    }
```

Comment: O que exatamente vc não entendeu? Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), `indexOf` retorna a posição do `objeto` no array `objetos`, ou `-1` caso ele não esteja no array. Então se o retorno for diferente de `-1`, é porque o elemento já existe. Era essa a dúvida?

Answer (score -3):

Talvez seja melhor entender isso na prática:

```html
<input type="text" id="campo">
<input type="button" value="Adicionar" onClick="adicionar()">
```

```js
var objetos = ['cadeira', 'impressora', 'garfo']
    console.log('Esses são os objetos já adicionados: '+objetos);

    function adicionar(){
        var objeto = document.getElementById('campo').value
        //Verifica se input com ID = "campo" está vazio
       if(objeto === '' ){ 
       //Estava vazio, então mostre o alerta
            alert('adicione um valor') 
        // Procura alguma correspondência positiva de índice (que é numérica e pode ir de 0 a N números), caso essa correspondência não seja encontrada, isso significa que ela é === a -1, logo é um novo elemento e pode ser adicionado.
        } else if(objetos.indexOf(objeto) === -1){  
          objetos.push(objeto);
          console.log(objetos);
          // o elemento foi encontrado em um dos índices, ou seja, era !== -1, enão ele já se encontra em algum local da matriz e não precisa ser adicionado novamente.
       } else {
           alert('O objeto '+objeto +' já foi adicionado')
       }  
    }
```

Aqui tem um exemplo prático: https://jsfiddle.net/s2zj1tvm/